# Windows Phone crashes in Release

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I have made a Windows Phone application with Xamarin and Mvvmcross. When debugging the application it works perfectly. So the application was uploaded to the app store. but when the application got downloaded and run from the store it shut down immidiately after the icon gets clicked. So now i found out that the application does not work when running it on a device in release mode. (on a emulator it works fine).

First i got this exception

> Error 1   Error : DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004. See log file '~project.WinPhone\obj\Release\MDIL\MDILXapCompileLog.txt' for more details.

in this file there was an error

> Compile filter argument specified non-existent file: ~project.WinPhone\obj\Release\MSIL\nl-NL\project.resources.dll
>   Invalid argument

This error made it unable to deploy the application to the device in release mode. I still have no idea why i got this error and how i am supposed to solve it. But i found a form of workaround by creating a 'nl-NL' map in the MSIL and adding the resource.dll to it. This made it able to deploy the application.

But when deploying the application in this state it crashed immediately. with the native debugger i could get it to break. it gave me this exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x775E062F (COMBASE.DLL) in project.WinPhone.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x04F80AB8, 0x00000006).

Clicking on the Disassembly it had it's pointer on  this line

> 77808534  bl          SignalStartWerSvc (777FED78h)

It probably has something to do with my localizedresources, where i define some `.resx` files for filling the app with text. I did find out that this is causing me some problem with WP but i am not sure what i could do against it, i cannot use `.resw` files as have been suggested.

Has anyone ever had this sort of issue before and does anyone know how to solve it? It is keeping me from placing a working application on the app store, which is really frustrating.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Xamarin, unless you are using Xamarin.Forms?... but it sounds like you might have an old project or old library that is not using the multilingual toolkit...i.e. do you have `.resw` or `.resx` resource files in your project(s)? as stating back with WP8.1, `multi-lingual `.resw` are required. Any `.resx` files made to be converted to `.resw` files and retested in release mode on an actual device.

Comment: I indeed have a 'LocalizedResources' project in the solution with `.resx` files for localization. Visual studio only gives me the option to use `.resx` files but no `.resw` files. Can you tell me how i am supposed to fix this problem?

Comment: Via `Tools` menu in VS, `Enable Multilingual Toolkit` (I think, do not have it in front of me) assuming it is installed @ https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit . Once enabled, normally all you have to do is rename the current `.resx` to `.resw` and via the `Project` menu add your translation language(s)... Details are on mdsn, but I do not have a link handy.

Comment: I changed my `.resx` file to `.resw`. Problem is the Mulitlingual toolkit does not work as it does not recognize the `.resw` file as a resource file. Also i cannot get any resources out of the `.resw` file, it just returns null. And i still get the `MdilXapCompile.exe` error. so does is not working :(